# .htaccess rewrite non-www to www even if there's a trailing subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, no-www

I'm trying to redirect a non-www URL to a www URL. That's simple, but ... when the URL contains a real subdirectory the redirect to www doesn't work.

Working: **site.com** redirects to **www.site.com**, that's good

But: **site.com/test** (is actual subdirectory) doesn't redirect to **www.site.com/test**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=development.site.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=staging.site.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

So in the .htaccess file above (which is located in the root) the **!^www. [NC]** part doesn't work when the incoming URL is for example: **site.com/testing**